How to remove the fear?
Recently, I was got cyberbullied by my schoolmate. yeah, I am not student. I'm depressed. I remove all contact and block them but I can't remove my anxiety and fear.
Oh yeah, I feel that I am not sotapanna again because I was lying to those cyberbulliers. After lying, I am so anxiety.

The Dhammapada says bullies are born in hell. You should feel sorry for bullies.


He who inflicts violence on those who are unarmed, and offends those who are inoffensive, will soon come upon one of these ten
states:

138-140 Sharp pain, or disaster, bodily injury, serious illness, or
derangement of mind, trouble from the government, or grave charges,
loss of relatives, or loss of wealth, or houses destroyed by ravaging
fire; upon dissolution of the body that ignorant man is born in hell.
Dhammapada

If you were lying, this can also lead to hell (AN 10.211). Therefore, you should confess your lying to the Buddha and commit to not speak lies again. MN 61 says:

When someone is not ashamed to tell a deliberate lie, there is no bad deed they would not do, I say. So you should train like this: ‘I will not tell a lie, even for a joke.’
‘This act of speech that I have done leads to hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting both. It’s unskillful, with suffering as its outcome and result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should confess, reveal, and clarify such a deed to the Teacher or a sensible spiritual companion. And having revealed it you should restrain yourself in future.
MN 61

When you tell deliberate lies, you cease to be a Buddhist (MN 61). Therefore, it is normal & expected you feel anxiety when you tell lies (AN 11.2; AN 10.61).
You remove fear & anxiety by confessing your transgressions to the Buddha. You stop/prevent fear & anxiety by not telling any lies and by not associating with immoral people.
